# Editing 3.4 screen in mainframe

Tags: dataset, screen, mainframe, legacy, zos

I frequently use my development datasets (PO's mainly) such as: code, JCL, output datasets. And then I have few prod datasets that I frequently access as well. How do I go about editing the screen to customize the datasets. I see more spaces but only one line for input dataset is given by IBM.

Is there any way to edit this without disrupting anything else ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

This is normally done via a [personal dataset list](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=i-using-personal-data-set-lists-library-lists).  Once created, you can key `dslist <listname>` on any Command line on any ISPF screen and get a 3.4 style list of your datasets.

Answer (score 1):

EZYEDIT is a productivity tool from Broadcom Inc. which allows you to create and save lists of frequently used datasets. Each dataset name can be assigned to a number. You can invoke the datasets by inputting the appropriate number. Upto 996 dataset names can be stored.

More info [here](https://techdocs.broadcom.com/us/en/ca-mainframe-software/traditional-management/ca-pdsman-pds-library-management/7-7/using/ezyedit.html)